# Excel VBA File open is slow due to button

Tags: excel, vba

After several hours of debugging I am able to pin point the issue with opening of an Excel file with VBA code in it. Opening the workbook costs around 60 seconds as this is unacceptable I need to find a way to solve this issue. The file extension is xlsb, I also tried xlsm but it has the same result.

The only reason I could find (after several hours of debugging) was that the button SEND with refece
to the InvokeWS is causing the delay in opening. When I remove the button, save the file and open it
it opens in 1 second. But with the button it costs 60 times more.

The question is how can I solve this?

The sub has the following code:

```
Sub InvokeWS()
    
    Range("B6").Value = ""
    Range("B7").Value = ""
    Range("B8").Value = ""
    
    '==FIRST CREATE THE XML FILE
    Call CreateXML
    
    '==THEN SEND XML VIA WS
    Call WebServiceCall

End Sub
```

The Sub calles 2 modules with quite some lines of VBA code but when loading the workbook with the modules removed the slow loading still exists so it can't be the code of these two modules. I have the feeling that this is due to the button itself.

Has anyone of you seen this issue before?

Comment: Never seen anything like what you're describing.  If this is an ActiveX button then try replacing it with a shape linked to the macro.

Comment: I will attest that I have had similar issues with ActiveX buttons - I no longer use ActiveX buttons on my worksheets due to the complications that come with them. Much easier to use shapes like @TimWilliams suggested.

Comment: I've seen buttons slow down the loading of the file they are in. I think that is what you are saying is happening, as opposed to somehow the button's click event performing slowly. You can fake a button: Use a cell and the `Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)`  Sub to call InvokeWS. No buttons or shapes at all. Not ideal, anyone can tab to that cell by accident. But it will work. Make it visually distinctive.

Comment: Tim Williams, in times of trouble a small insight from outside your line of sight really helps. The ActiveX button was indeed the problem. Replacing them with a shape and a link to the macro did the trick. Thanks!